Process one request and enqueue other requests using Semaphore in Middleware
I am using semaphore to handle one request at a time and enqueue other request and process  in sequence. But when I run the code it run first request and drop other request. What I am doing wrong here? In action method I am calling a service.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

public class OneRequestAtATimeMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<HttpContext> _queue = new ConcurrentQueue<HttpContext>();

    public OneRequestAtATimeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
        if (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<OneRequestAtATime>() != null)
        {
            if (!await _lock.WaitAsync(TimeSpan.Zero))
            {
                _queue.Enqueue(context);
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                await _next(context);

                while (_queue.TryDequeue(out var nextContext))
                {
                    await _next(nextContext);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.Release();

                if (_queue.TryPeek(out var nextContext))
                {
                    await InvokeAsync(nextContext);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class OneRequestAtATime : Attribute { }


Hi Alamzaib, could you modify the middleware code like this, and tell me if it works for you. Thanks~

Thanks for commenting. No it did not resolve the issue. Second request still dropping.

Hi Alamzaib, I updated the link, please check again, thanks for your patience.

It says Request has finished and HttpContext disposed.
Object name: 'HttpContext'. when I send 2 request simultaneously

Hi Alamzaib, could you create a brand new sample project which can reproduce the issue? I am happy to investigate the issue. And please hide your sensitive information if any.

Issue resolved kindly check my answer.

ChatGPT helped me to resolve the issue.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

     public class OneRequestAtATimeMiddleware
     {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _lock = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 
     1); // Static to ensure one lock for all requests.

    public OneRequestAtATimeMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
        if (endpoint?.Metadata?.GetMetadata<OneRequestAtATime>() != null)
        {
            await _lock.WaitAsync();
            try
            {

                await _next(context);
            }
            finally
            {
                _lock.Release();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class OneRequestAtATime : Attribute { }

